# using tuples from finditer as startpos/endpos for further search

Tags: python, object, tuples, match

I wrote some code that in the end shall parse a document containing mainly dates and additional data. and return the date with that corresponding data.

So far I got with some help of you guys:

```
f = open("Krupp.txt", "r")
contents = f.read()

f.close() #close the file
with open("testoutput.txt", "a+") as f:
    #my regex to find german dates in special format
    for m in re.finditer("(Montag|Dienstag|Mittwoch|Donnerstag|Freitag|Samstag|Sonnabend|Sonntag)(, )([123][0-9]|[1-9])(. )(Januar|Februar|März|April|Mai|Juni|Juli|August|September|Oktober|November|Dezember)( )([0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])", contents):
    #print whole matchobject
    print m.group(0)
```

**the file looks like:**

```
Donnerstag, 16. März 2014

17:30 Uhr

19:00 Uhr

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

Details
Montag, 20. Oktober 2011

18:00 Uhr

19:30 Uhr

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

**My Output, if printed, looks like:**

```
Donnerstag, 16. März 2014

Montag, 20. Oktober 2011
```

Now I would like to be abled to use those dates as startpos and endpos for further searches. But I don't get how I could index those dates.

If I use group(1) it returns just "Donnerstag" and "Montag". If I use group(2) it returns "," and so on.

I understand, that my `matchobject` is a group of tuples. But how can I use those tuples? I want to be abled to search between date 3 and 5 or date 2 and 9.

Please write the answer for noobs :)
Thank you

Comment: I suggest you to provide your ideal output, the current description is not clear.

Comment: Okay. For example what would I have to write if I wanted to print just the 2nd or 5th date?

Comment: That's the point. The input file you provided which does not contain 2nd, 3rd, 5th or 9th date. While asking question with input and ideal output, it will be better to have relation between them. You want to get `16` and `20` in your example input file, don't you?